# How to package a Groovy class or Groovy project using Ant Build scripts?

Tags: groovy, build, ant, packaging

```
Error: Could not find or load main class GroovyDemoClass
```

I am using a build.xml file similar to below

```
<project>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/GroovyDemoClass.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="GroovyDemoClass"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/GroovyDemoClass.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

My doubt is that Can ANT identifies the Groovy class files like Java class files

Comment: Yes, finally the compiled java/groovy are the same. Except groovy requires groovy-all-xxx.jar to run.

Comment: But Its not working right. I replaced the same file with .java extension. Its working fine

Comment: ok. i missed how you do compile. it should be groovyc instead of javac. http://groovy-lang.org/groovyc.html#ThegroovycAntTask-groovyc